# python struct module packing and unpacking return values

Tags: python, c, struct

I am using struct module for serializing the data to send the data over socket. I observed that **struct.pack(frmt, value1, ...)** returns a string of the value 1 in ***two bytes*** hexadecimal format. Why does it return ***only in two bytes format***? There should be some reason. Maybe I am missing something while understanding struct class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is lacking [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation of the [python struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

If you concern about the size of the packed result read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)